# Download image via HttpRequest - poor quality

Tags: php, image, httprequest

I am working at gallery page.
Idea is to give access to product photos depending on http header for some security reasons. I am using Tom Slankard library (https://gist.github.com/twslankard/989974).

Everything seems to work ok but I got stripped images with different RGB values and/or have moved pixels and have no idea why.

my code:

```php
<?php
include("HttpRequest.php");

        $r = new HttpRequest($link);
        try {
            $r->send();
            echo $r->getStatus()."\n";

            if ($r->getStatus() == 200) {

             $foto = $r->getResponseBody();
             $out=   fopen('product.jpg', "w");
             fwrite($out, $aaa, strlen($foto));
             fclose($out);
            }
        } catch (HttpException $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }


?>
```

Result image is: 
https://i.imgsafe.org/dba7fac3ab.jpg

Comment: Does it still mangle the image if you change fopen('product.jpg', 'w') to fopen('product.jpg', 'wb')?

Comment: Yes it is still the same.